# Get code from git base on commit id

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using git and bitbucket.  Please guide me a way to download or pull all code base on commit id. 
Eg commit ids are "1", "2", "3", I want dowload code from "1" and "2".

Please help!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got you right. When you do initial clone:

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git -b commit_id
```

When you have repository already cloned:

```
git fetch                  # fetches all new commits from remote
git checkout commit_id     # changes current HEAD to desired commit
```

Or if you need to download only code (without git history):

```
# extension zip may be changed to tar.gz for example
wget https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame/get/commit_id.zip
```

Be careful with last one, if this repo is private, you'll need to specify authorization for wget. To use wget with authorization:

```
wget --http-user=username --http-password=password https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame/get/commit_id.zip
```